# ExceptionFilterAttribute in Azure Functions

Tags: asp.net-web-api, migration, azure-functions

I'm trying to migrate a WebAPI application to Azure Functions.

I have searched on the net and haven't found anything equivalent to ExceptionFilterAttribute supported in Azure Functions.

Does this mean that to migrate this feature, we should wrap the code of every function in try catch blocks and then run the same code to process the Exception? Are there any other workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Function Filters](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Function-Filters) in Azure Functions, particularly `ErrorHandler`.

Just keep in mind

> This features is still in preview. Please be cautious using this in production applications.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know about this. No info in Microsoft sites.
The ExceptionFilterAttribute modifies the context.Response object to return some response to the user, but for FunctionExceptionFilterAttribute there doesn't seem to be an equivalent way to do that?

Comment: No, it's not fully equivalent functionally. Because of many possible trigger types, they didn't add features to modify http response (yet?)